# Dependency Injection in View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection

Could someone explain dependency injection in View Controller, how we can get rid of optionals? I have read numerous articles on it but couldn't get much clarity of it. And is it a good approach to pass data from one VC to another?

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    var number: [String]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.printNumbers()
    }

    func printNumbers() {
        guard let number = self.number else { return }

        print(number)
    }
}

//+++++++ In First View Controller +++++++++++++++++

@IBAction func pushToSecondVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let secondViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as SecondVC
    secondViewController.number = self.numbers
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Does this not work for you? In your 2nd view controller, do you not get the values?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, if you simply want to get rid of optionals, replace your `var number: [String]?` with `var number = [String]()`. This will create an empty array.

When you have to access this property, you no longer need to unwrap it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of them, but then you'll need to initiate them from code instead of storyboard.
If you wanna use something similar initiate method you have up there, I think the best you can do is to change optionals to force unwrapped types and have some kind of static initiator function, something like this:

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var number: [String]!

    static func initiateFromStoryboard(with number: [String]) -> ViewController {
        let viewController = UIStoryBoard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as! ViewController
        viewController.number = number
        return viewController
    }
}

//// Use it like:
...
let vc = ViewController.initiateFromStoryboard(with: ["1","2"])
navigationController?.push(vc)
```

Ofc. the drawback is that you need to keep an eye on the `number` property to be always set before using it, otherwise your code will crash.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options you have if you want to get rid of optionals:

1. Don't make them optional and give them a default value. This only works if there are sensible defaults of course.
2. Make them implicitly unwrapped. They will still be optionals, but you won't have to deal with unwrapping them. This only works if you know for sure that the presenting view controller provides values for them.
3. Use custom initialisers that take a value and assign the properties when the view controller initialises. This is nice and clean, but it won't work well with storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Others here have suggested setting initial values for `var`. While this means less optionals, the problem here is that its easy to forget to set a `var`, which could lead to tricky to diagnose problems.

I favour `private` implicitly unwrapped optionals e.g.

```
private var number: [String]!
private (set) var someBool: Bool! // private (set) makes it visible but not setable
```

and then a `configure` func on each view controller (or any object instantiated from a storyboard of nib), e.g.

```
configure(number: [String], someBool: Bool) {
    self.number = number
    self.someBool = someBool
}
```

Unwrapped optionals will crash on use if not set, and as they're private, they can't be accidentally updated from outside the class itself.